# How does one show that $A \cong T \times A $ when $T$ is terminal?

Tags: category-theory

I want to show:

$$ A \cong T \times A $$

so for that I wanted to do $f;g = 1_A$ and $g;f = 1_{T \times A}$. The first one is easy $f;g = 1_A$ because we know $T \times A$ is a limit so for any other cone $(C,\{\gamma_A,\gamma_T\})$ of the disconnected objects $T$,$A$ we have the factorization:

$$ \gamma_A = f;g$$

in particular for $\gamma_A = 1_A$. So it works.

But how do we show the other direction? I assume something to do with the fact that $T$ is terminal (i.e. admits unique morphisms to it from any object) but this simple fact is escaping me right now. Any idea?

Comment: Use the Yoneda lemma; show that $\text{Hom}(-, A) \cong \text{Hom}(-, T \times A)$ as functors.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I know this is embarrassing but I just started with CT so idk what Yoneda's lemma is. I think it would be very strange to use it since it has been taught to me yet...

Comment: If you don't know the Yoneda lemma then you can't even prove that limits are unique up to unique isomorphism yet; I recommend that you learn the Yoneda lemma as soon as possible.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I know how to prove two limits are isomorphic without appealing to that lemma. It comes out naturally when one connects the two limits with a unique isomorphism...hmmm...

Comment: A brute force approach is to simply write out what the isomorphism is and prove that it is an isomorphism. The latter step will require using the universal properties of products and the terminal object.

Comment: @DerekElkins how do you use the terminal object property to finish this? I don't see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the brute-force approach I mentioned in the comments. This is definitely not the slickest way.

Let $\pi_i : A_1\times A_2\to A_i$ be projections of the product $A_1\times A_2$. Let $\langle f,g\rangle : B\to A_1\times A_2$ where $f: B\to A_1$ and $g : B\to A_2$ be the unique morphism (for any $B$, $f$, and $g$) whose existence is guaranteed by the universal property. The universal property can then be stated as: $\pi_i\circ\langle f_1,f_2\rangle = f_i$ and $\langle \pi_1\circ g,\pi_2\circ g\rangle = g$ for any pair of arrows $f_i: B\to A_i$ for any $B$ and any $g : C \to A_1\times A_2$ and any $C$.

Let $1$ be a terminal object and $!_A : A\to 1$ be the unique morphism (for each $A$) whose existence is guaranteed by the universal property of terminal objects. The universal property can then be stated as: $!_A = f$ for any $f : A\to 1$ for any $A$.

Claim: $\pi_2 : 1\times A \to A$ and $\langle !_A,id_A\rangle : A\to 1\times A$ form an isomorphism, i.e. are mutually inverse. We need to show $$\begin{align}\pi_2\circ\langle!_A,id_A\rangle & = id_A\qquad  \text{ and }\\
\langle !_A,id_A\rangle\circ\pi_2 & = id_{1\times A}\end{align}$$
The first holds immediately via the universal property for products. For the second, we use the second part of the universal property of products which implies that if $\pi_i\circ f=\pi_i\circ g$ for $i\in\{1,2\}$ then $f=g$. (Why?) Let's try to prove $$\begin{align}\pi_1\circ\langle !_A,id_A\rangle\circ\pi_2 & = \pi_1\circ id_{1\times A}\\ \pi_2\circ\langle !_A,id_A\rangle\circ\pi_2 & = \pi_2\circ id_{1\times A}\end{align}$$ The second immediately follows from the universal property for products. For the former we get $$\begin{align}\pi_1\circ\langle !_A,id_A\rangle\circ\pi_2 & = {!_A}\circ \pi_2 \\ & = {!_{1\times A}} \\ & = \pi_1 \\ & = \pi_1\circ id_{1\times A}\\\end{align}$$
The $!_A\circ\pi_2 = {!_{1\times A}}$ and $!_{1\times A} = \pi_1$ both used the universal property of terminal objects. As mentioned, we finish by using the universal property of $1\times A$ to get $$\begin{align}\langle\pi_1\circ\langle!_A,id_A\rangle\circ\pi_2,\pi_2\circ\langle!_A,id_A\rangle\circ\pi_2\rangle & =\langle\pi_1\circ id_{1\times A},\pi_2\circ id_{1\times A}\rangle\\ & = id_{1\times A}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Show that $A$ satisfies the universal property for $T\times A$. Let $\pi_T=!$ (the unique map to $T$), and let $\pi_A=1_A$ (the identity on $A$). Now let $f:B\to T$ and $g:B\to A$ be any arrows. Define $h:B\to A$ by $h=g$. Then $\pi_T\circ h=f$ since there is only one map $B\to T$ and $\pi_A\circ h=1_A\circ g=g$. Furthermore, if $h':B\to A$ is another such map satisfying these relations, then $$h'=1_A\circ h'=\pi_A\circ h'=\pi_A\circ h=1_A\circ h=h,$$ which gives uniqueness. Since products are unique up to isomorphism, we conclude $A\cong T\times A.$

Why does everyone think you need Yoneda to prove something so basic?

Comment: how and where did you use the fact that $T$ was terminal?

Comment: There's a unique map from any object into $T,$ so there was no choice of $f$ at all - any map $B\to T$ must be the unique map $B\to T$ given by the universal property of $T.$ That $f$ factors as $B\to A\to T$ again follows because there is a unique map from any object to $T$: you have maps $B\to A$ and $A\to T,$ so the composition is a (hence the) map $B\to T.$

Answer (score 0):

The arrows from some object $B$ to $T\times A$ correspond naturally to pairs
of arrows $(f,g)$ where $f:B\to T$ and $g:B\to A$. But there's only one arrow
from $B$ to $T$, so the arrows $B\to T\times A$ correspond naturally to the arrows
from $B\to A$. So there's a natural equivalence of Hom-functors $\text{Hom}(-,A)$
and $\text{Hom}(-,T\times A)$. So $A$ is isomorphic to $T\times A$
(basically by Yoneda).

Comment: In a more calculational form: $$\begin{align}\text{Hom}(-,T\times A) & \cong \text{Hom}(-,T)\times\text{Hom}(-,A)\\& \cong 1\times\text{Hom}(-,A)\\&\cong\text{Hom}(-,A)\end{align}$$ Then Yoneda as usual. The first isomorphism is the universal property of products (in the form of representability). The second is the universal property of the terminal object. The final is just set-theoretic reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

For a proof from first principles (with functors and Yoneda officially not yet in sight), have a look at Theorem 26 and then Theorem 27(i) of  this [Gentle Introduction](https://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/GentleIntro.pdf).

Comment: /me endeavors to influence Peter Smith to add a chapter on (co)ends to this introduction, or at least mention them...

Comment: I'll get back to that Introduction one day, I hope (when another book is off to the publishers ...). Promises, promises ...